# Is lamb meat called ‘agnew’?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Wikipedia, specifically at the entry on the Middle English creole hypothesis:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_creole_hypothesis

it appears that ‘agnew’ is being listed as being the aristocratic form of ‘lamb meat’, but I cannot find confirmation of that anywhere, including the online dictionary of Merriam-Webster. Can anyone confirm/refute this entry?

Comment: All I can tell you is that 'agneau' is French for lamb, but you probably knew that.

Comment: It is no longer on Wikipedia

Comment: Fixed at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never heard or seen this, and the OED doesn't list it.  It looks to me as if somebody took as examples the Norman French *mouton* for mutton and *boeuf* for beef, as opposed to Saxon *sheep* and *cow*, (which are well-known), and decided to buttress the argument by adding in *agnew* without checking whether it is actually used.

Comment: Very clearly, this was a joke, belittling once again Spiro T. Agnew, once Vice-President of the United States under the Nixon administration (q.v). Agnew was forced to resign under indictment for corruption, shortly before Nixon was forced to resign under threat of impeachment, leaving the United States with an unelected President and Vice-President. These were all Republicans, and there is a vicious presidential election going on right now.

Comment: It's interesting to note that we use *mutton, beef, pork* for the **cooked** forms, even though they were taken from the Norman conquerors names for the **living animals**. I think that's because our ancestors had to serve it cooked to them demned French overlords in their castles and manors, so over time the meat on the boss's plate came to be known by the boss's word for it. The peasant working on the farm just had to carry on shovelling lamb/cow/pig-shit, so he continued using his existing native word for the source thereof.

Comment: @Johnlawler:  I think you're right (demonstrating again the flaw with Wikipedia).  If you make that an answer, the people who keep upvoting my answer can vote for yours instead. (I certainly would).